# Could someone please help to take a loot at this symbol that looks like E or L?

Tags: fonts

could someone please help to take a loot at this symbol

[image]

I've tried E or L

```
$\mathscr{L}$

$\mathcal{L}$

$\mathcal{E}$

$\mathscr{E}$
```

none of them renders that symbol.

any clue would be appreciated.

Comment: `\mathfrak{L}` .

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Fraktur, from (eg) `mathfonts` package  `\mathfrak{L}`